# Input Box with multiple values in the same field

Tags: excel, vba, criteria, inputbox

I have a macro created which does the following:

1. Asks for a value to be entered in an Input Box
2. Then searches for this value in all Workbooks in a specific folder
3. Returns (copies) specific cells from the same row the value found in a new worksheet.

However, i would like to search all those different Workbooks based on multiple values. For example to search if text "AXL" or "JBO" exist in any of the Workbooks and returns the values as per my code.

Any help and even a different approach to what i'm trying to achive is more than welcome.
Thanks for your time!

```
Sub SearchFolders()
Dim fso As Object
Dim fld As Object
Dim strSearch As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim wOut As Worksheet
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rFound As Range
Dim strFirstAddress As String


On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


strPath = "C:\Users\cmkon\Desktop\CAMS"
strSearch = InputBox("Enter Criteria")


Set wOut = Worksheets.Add
lRow = 1
With wOut
    .Cells(lRow, 1) = "Workbook"
    .Cells(lRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
    .Cells(lRow, 3) = "Cell"
    .Cells(lRow, 4) = "Text in Cell"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(strPath)


    strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.xls*")
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open _
          (Filename:=strPath & "\" & strFile, _
          UpdateLinks:=0, _
          ReadOnly:=True, _
          AddToMRU:=False)


        For Each wks In wbk.Worksheets
        Set rFound = wks.UsedRange.Find(strSearch)
         
                    
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                strFirstAddress = rFound.Address
            End If
            Do
                If rFound Is Nothing Then
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    lRow = lRow + 1
                    .Cells(lRow, 1) = wbk.Name
                    .Cells(lRow, 2) = wks.Name
                    .Cells(lRow, 3) = rFound.Address
                    .Cells(lRow, 4) = rFound.Value
                End If
                Set rFound = wks.Cells.FindNext(After:=rFound)
            Loop While strFirstAddress <> rFound.Address
        Next


        wbk.Close (False)
        strFile = Dir
    Loop
    .Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

  
MsgBox "Done"

ExitHandler:
Set wOut = Nothing
Set wks = Nothing
Set wbk = Nothing
Set fld = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question? It seems like you only stated your requirements. And also, what have you attempted?

Comment: Perhaps indicate a delimiter to identify in the `InputBox` e.g. `AXL|JBO` and create an array out of `strSearch` using `Split` method. Enclose `Set rFound = wks.UsedRange.Find(strSearch)` with a loop through the array, searching for each item in the array, if any point that `Not rFound Is Nothing` is `True` then exit the loop and insert the information..

Comment: Hello Raymond, thanks for your feedback! What you suggest is what i'm trying to do but i'm not sure how to successfully to create the loop. at which row to insert the commands.

Comment: @RaymondWu; I though to add [Dim s As Variant] and [s = Split(InputboxValue, "|")]. but i'm not sure how and where to start and end the loop. If you could guide me.

Comment: @RaymondWu , I found the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know! You can submit your own answer and accept it later on.

Answer (score -1):

My final code!

```
Sub SearchFolders()

Dim fso As Object
Dim fld As Object
Dim strSearch As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim wOut As Worksheet
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rFound As Range
Dim strFirstAddress As String

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

strPath = "C:\Users\cmkon\Desktop\CAMS"
strSearch = InputBox("Enter Criteria")

Dim MyArray() As String, I As Variant
MyArray = Split(strSearch, ";")

For Each I In MyArray

Set wOut = Worksheets.Add
lRow = 1
With wOut
    .Cells(lRow, 1) = "Workbook"
    .Cells(lRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
    .Cells(lRow, 3) = "Cell"
    .Cells(lRow, 4) = "Text in Cell"
    .Cells(lRow, 5) = "Instructions"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(strPath)

    strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.xls*") 
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open _
          (Filename:=strPath & "\" & strFile, _
          UpdateLinks:=0, _
          ReadOnly:=True, _
          AddToMRU:=False)


        For Each wks In wbk.Worksheets
        Set rFound = wks.UsedRange.Find(I)
       
                    
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                strFirstAddress = rFound.Address
            End If
            Do
                If rFound Is Nothing Then
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    lRow = lRow + 1
                   .Cells(lRow, 1) = wbk.Name
                   .Cells(lRow, 2) = wks.Name
                   .Cells(lRow, 3) = rFound.Address
                   .Cells(lRow, 4) = rFound.Value
             
                End If
                Set rFound = wks.Cells.FindNext(After:=rFound)
            Loop While strFirstAddress <> rFound.Address
        Next

        wbk.Close (False)
        strFile = Dir
    Loop
    .Columns("A:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
Next I MsgBox "Done"

ExitHandler:
Set wOut = Nothing
Set wks = Nothing
Set wbk = Nothing
Set fld = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
Resume ExitHandler

End Sub
```

Comment: This is not an answer, i suggest, you edit your existing question